# Lightweight teaching tool (alternative to Moodle)

Tags: web-apps, educational

I want an open LMS that support the following features:

- Creating of tests where studens can choose one or multiple options that may be graded;
- Presence/non-presence and marks may be noted and viewed as a table;
- Files may be updated by students (associated with tasks);
- Working without Internet connection (in LAN);

I don't want big "enterprisey" things, I'd prefer:

- Software runnable from it's own lightweight web server, or runnable from Nginx;
- Software that can work without a database, or using Sqlite, or with LevelDB (or another lightweight key/value storage);
- Preferrably not PHP (I just don't like it);

I plan running it from laptop (or even smartphone) or from a weak VPS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### RELATE (maybe old name is CourseFlow?)

URI: https://github.com/inducer/relate

- Quizs are supported and are rather advanced. The system can even run submitted programs in Docker
- Files can be attached to quiz answers (relies on emails)
- Simple, not overloaded UI
- Django, not PHP. I expect Nginx setup be straightforward
- Works well with (and even defaults to) Sqlite.
- Seems intranet-friendly (no external javascript dependencies)
- Git-based, plaintext format for everything. No WYSIWG editors.

Some issues:

- Requires `bower` (and thus NodeJS) at deployment time. Workaround: supply those static files manually;
- Likes e-mails. If mailing is not set up, some things won't work and though exceptions.
- You can't create content from within the platform itself. You need to push it to Git and it becomes availble in RELATE.

Comment: Deployed.